# How do I share a SSIS project on Azure devops

Tags: sql-server, git, azure-devops, ssis, etl

We have several SSIS projects on Azure DevOps, everytime I pull the project and another user committed before it destroys my dtproj file. I tried to put the file in the gitignore but then the project do not show me the new files created by other users. I think the problem is that the credentials are stored encrypted inside the file and when the user uploads his credentials it destroys mine.
Any idea how to avoid this error?

> Warning loading ETLXXX.dtproj: Warning: Failed to decrypt sensitive data in a project with a user key. You may not be the user who encrypted this project, or you are not using the same machine that was used to save the project. If the sensitive data is a parameter value, the value may be required to run the package on the Integration Services server.
> ETLXXX.dtproj 0

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the package protection level configuration. You should not encrypt the package with the user key in production. This should only be used in the development phase or in some rare cases after being deployed.

I recommend reading more about the SSIS package access control and how it should be changed during the package lifecycle:

- [Access Control for Sensitive Data in Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Securing Your SSIS Packages Using Package Protection Level](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/)